# How to use Square IN-APP PAYMENTS SDK below minSdkVersion of 21. The SDK is bounding to use minSDKVersion to be 21

Tags: android, sdk, square, in-app

How to use Square IN-APP PAYMENTS SDK below minSdkVersion of 21. The SDK is bounding to use minSDKVersion to be 21. But my project is addressing uptill minSdkVersion of 17. How to let minSdkVersion to be 17 and also to use sqaure in-app sdk in my App ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently that's not possible. Due to the way the In-App Payments SDK was built, it requires a minimum version of 21, thus it will not work with anything below that.

Comment: Agreed. But my app currently addresses user upto minSDK of 17. Any wayout for processing the payment for user among 17- 20 SDK range ? Otherwise i have to omit users who are having below SDK 21 and it will affect my project. Any wayout ?